# Error 203 when using Google People API

Tags: c++, qt, google-people-api

The Google People API allows to read and manage contacts. i tried executing a code that would allow for me to obtain, however, i get error 203. Here is my code

```
QUrl url("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/me}/connections");
url.addQueryItem("pageToken", nextPageToken);

QNetworkRequest* request = new QNetworkRequest( url );
request->setHeader( QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json" );
request->setRawHeader( "Authorization", QString( "Bearer %1" ).arg( this->_oAuth2->token() ).toLatin1() );

return this->m_networkManager->get(*request);
```

However, i get error 203.
What am i doing wrong?.

Comment: Looks like this isn't really an error: https://httpstatuses.com/203

Comment: Indeed, but i couldn't receive any content.. from your link, i'm guessing the network was transformed into a proxy, thereby preventing data to be received.